# How can I set up wifi in Ubuntu to monitor and limit user activity and bandwidth usage?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, router

In my office, I have a broadband connection, an Ubuntu box and a wifi router. I want to share my broadband connection in my office. How can I setup everything along with a monitoring application in that Ubuntu box, so that I can monitor user's (who will be connected through that wifi router) usage, traffic, and bandwidth and also can limit them to certain data use if possible.

Comment: This is something you need to do at the router level rather than at OS level. Look for/read about QoS relating to your router model.

Comment: @jjk_charles That really should be an answer, not a comment, as it does not appear to seek clarification about or suggest improvement to the question.

Comment: Sure, I'll re-post the same as an answer (with a bit more details added)! Felt it would be too short for an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is something you need to do at the router level rather than at OS level. Look for/read about [QoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) relating to your router model.

Since you asked about achieving it at OS level (linux), if at all you have access to all the machines, you can use bandwidth shaping tools installed/configured to achieve something similar. You can try [Trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle) which I have personally tried in Ubuntu and works great (its pretty easy to configure too). The flip side of this approach is that, this only limits the maximum bandwidth that particular machine can consume and doesn't actually solve the problem of contention in the network itself. Say for instance, if you have installed Trickle (or any bandwidth shaping utility) in certain machines but not others, they could still clog the network.